# Chrome Developer Tool: how to track the javascript function in .js files?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, google-chrome-devtools

I am reading [the code](https://github.com/guille/chat-example) of a [chat project](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) as a demo for socket.io

The index.html include the script from socket.io.js
In socket.io.js, here is a snippet:

```
var io;

io = Manager(source, opts);
```

So I want to find out the definition for Manager.
What is an easiest way (alternative to F3 in Elipse) to get the definition of a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no generic way to navigate to arbitrary function definitions. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in an editor will bring up all function definitions in the current script.

Another option is, you can evaluate `Manager` in the console and click the URL reference in the response console message. This should work across all sources.